# rich:calendar popup="true" not opening the calendar popup in IE 10/9/8 but works fine in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, richfaces, internet-explorer-10

In my application, rich:calendar component is used and set `popup="true"`. When I click on the calendar image popup opens up in IE11. BUt it does not happen in IE10. When I debugged it in the developer tool. I found that the calendar element has the style "display:none" set for it. So I tried to change it from the client side adding the following code

```
$("#j_idt125\\:j_idt523PopupButton").click(function(){
    $("#j_idt125\\:j_idt523Content").css({ display: "table" });
});
```

`#j_idt125\\:j_idt523PopupButton` is the id of the calendar img button(set by the client" and  `"#j_idt125\\:j_idt523Content"` id of the popup calendar table. When I give an alert statement below this statement it shows both alert and calendar. But When I dont give the alert it is not showing the calendar. And the style property is not changing in the dom. Please give me some guidance on what is really happening there and also to make this work in all the other IE versions.

Comment: What version of RF are you using?

Comment: My richfaces version is 4.0

Comment: We have an unresolved bug filed for this, I'm afraid you'll have to upgrade to a newer version of RichFaces.

Comment: Thanks for the information Makhiel. It is a big application, So I cant simply change the version. And surprisingly even hacking in the javascript doesnt work in this issue. Please let me know if some one come across any solution for this, I will also do the same.                                                                                                          Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in JavaScript, you could try replacing the jQuery with a newer version.